# Angular 4/typescript best practice with cleaner code?

Tags: angular, typescript, coding-style

What is the best practice in Angular in this case?

In this example, I have a login form.

When the user clicks on the submit button, i call the onSignin method.

```
 onSignin(form: NgForm) {

  const email = form.value.email;
  const password = form.value.password;

  this.loginService.login(email, password).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.responseData = data;
      var dataBodyJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseData._body)
    },
    err => {
      try {
        var errorJSON = JSON.parse(err._body);
        var errorBody = errorJSON['Message']
        console.log(errorBody)
      }
    },
    () => {
      var dataBodyJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseData._body)
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', dataBodyJSON['Token']);
      window.location.href = "dashboard";
    }
  )
};
```

loginservice login method:

```
 login(username: string, password: string) {

        const headerParameters = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        const jsonBody = {
            "Username": username,
            "Password": password
        }

        return this.http.post('loginurl'', jsonBody,
            { headers: headerParameters })
    }
```

Would not be better way, if the logic is in the service class? I would pass back to the login component just the result, 
  and if I have to reuse the login method in another component, i dont need to write the logic 2 times.

also, in angular this javascript redirection is very bad practice, right?

Comment: no once you submitted your input(username,password), you are waiting for response(whether login correct or not ). You need not know when it will respond back. So once you receive data you can subscribe to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not all developers agree on best practices, however most would encourage encapsulation.  So, yes, if you want to share code between components, then I strongly recommend putting it in a shared class.  In Angular 2+ I would set this up as a provider.

Create your class with the @injectable metadata:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class SomeProvider {
  // Code here
}
```

In your main module you set it up using the provider Metadata:

```
import {SomeProvider } from "../dir/to/provider/someprovider.service";
@NgModule({
    // Other code here
    providers : [SomeProvider]
})
```

And finally, you can inject this provider into a component's constructor using Angular's Dependency Injection syntax:

```
import {SomeProvider } from "../dir/to/provider/someprovider.service";
export class TaskCU {
    constructor(private someProvider: SomeProvider ) {
    };
    someMethod():any{
      someProvider.doSomething();
    }
}
```

You can also inject the shared code into Angular elements, such as a different provider.